# How to stop in the middle of a rappel without an autoblock?

Tags: safety, rappelling

Sometimes people rappel without a backup prussik, [such as when canyoning](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/in-canyoning-why-do-people-skip-a-backup-prusik/16619#16619) and sometimes an auto block needs to be adjusted. In either of these situations, is there a way to stop yourself in the middle of the rappel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple solution is to take the rope (both strands if rappelling on a doubled rope) below the device  and wrap the several times around your upper leg and hold your upper leg perpendicular to the ground (this keeps the rope from slipping off).

It's not particularly comfortable and you don't want to do it for an extended amount of time, but as a stopgap measure it works quite well.

To getting going again, point your leg towards the ground and  unwrap the rope.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I'd fancy trusting my life to wrapping the rope around my leg. The conventional way to escape a belay is to tie it off, [see here](http://www.vdiffclimbing.com/tieoff-belay/)

[image]

For extra safety you can clip the figure eight onto your harness using a carabiner.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65087/discussion-on-answer-by-liam-how-to-stop-in-the-middle-of-a-rappel-without-an-au).

Comment: I have moved it just so you can have a full chat about it. Once a conclusion is reached, please do fed back into answers.